# Why does my Java code not compile?

Tags: java, initialization

I have this fragment of code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addQuestion(){
    ViewController viewController ;
    viewController.createQuestion(int questionId, String theQuestion, String category, String correctAnswer);
    return "qFour";
}
```

and the line beginning 'viewController.createQuestion' is underlined in red saying variable `'viewController' might not have been initialized`.

1. when I try `ViewController viewController = null;` (i.e. initializing it, it complains again for another reason)
2. why does it need initializing?
3. can someone instruct me what is syntactically wrong with this code?

Comment: You are not calling it's constructor, so it hasn't been initialised.

Comment: "*why does it need initializing?*" - because this is how the Java language has been specified.

Comment: I. E. You need to do `ViewController viewController = new ViewController(...);`

Comment: @will sorry yeh I had ViewController viewController = new ViewController(); but it is now saying ';' expected even though ';' is in all the correct pages

Comment: this call viewController.createQuestion(...) look like a method definition, you should just pass the arguments without their types (that are already defined in method prototype), and of course declare and initialize those arguments before ...

Answer (score 3):

You must initialize your local variable `ViewController viewController` to a non-null value before using it.

- If you don't initialize it, your code won't compile, since an uninitialized variable can't be used.
- If you initialize it to null, `viewController.createQuestion(...)` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but why does it also complain about ViewController viewController = new ViewController();?

Comment: @RedBaron the error message should tell you that. We don't have your code, and we don't have the error message, so how could we know?

Comment: @JBNizet because you are psychics...
nah only kidding. but i have provided some code and the error message is awful in netbeans. it just says '.class' expected, ';' expected. what does that even mean? All semicolons are in the correct place..

Comment: If everything was in the correct place, it would compile. Where is th code? Where is the exact and complete error message? What line and column in the code does it refer to?

Comment: @JBNizet the code is in the question. the error message is what i wrote in my last comment but if you insist on having it in full here it is....'.class' expected ';' expected ';' expected ';' expected not a statement ';' expected....
basically, the viewController object should be calling the createQuestion method within its class but for some reason Java is saying I need semicolons even though i am sure i dont. does that make sense?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't compile because the viewController is not initialized. So, fix this issue. Then look at your method call: it specifies the types of the variables as if it was a method declaration.It must not. A method call is like `viewController.createQuestion(questionId, theQuestion, category, correctAnswer)`. Why are you doing Spring MVC if you don't know how to use variables and methods? Do basic things first.

Comment: @JBNizet i do know how to use vars and methods thanks mate. i've amended my error and it was just a simple case of having forgotten to throw an SQLException.